# Customized alignment of texts and inline equations

Tags: horizontal-alignment, alignment

I wish to make an environment (perhaps using macros) that works similar to 'align', but which works with *texts and inline equations* instead of ordinary equations.

[image]

The above image is the desired result, and I wish to make an environment 'newalign' using the following format.

```
\newenvironment{newalign}{  }{  }
\newcommand{\alignhere}[1]{  }
\newcommand{\notehere}{  }

\begin{newalign}
(some equation)
\alignhere{$\Rightarrow$} (some equation) \notehere (shortnote)\\
\alignhere{$\Rightarrow$} (some looooooooooooooooooooooooooooong equation) \notehere (shortnote)\\
\alignhere{$\Leftrightarrow$} (some equation) \notehere (shortnote)
\end{newalign}


\begin{newalign}
(some equation)\\
\alignhere{$=$} (some equation) \notehere (shortnote)\\
\alignhere{$=$} (some looooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooong equation) \notehere (shortnote)\\
\alignhere{$\subseteq$} (some equation) \notehere (shortnote)
\end{newalign}
```

1. The command \alignhere indicates the points of alignment using symbols such as \Rightarrow, \Leftrightarrow, =, \subseteq, etc.
2. When a long text (or equation) appears after \alignhere, it automatically breaks into multiple lines with indentations equal to the length of the symbol used in \alignhere{}.
3. The command \notehere makes a space of constant length, flushed to the right, with a short note (usually a single word) for each line.
4. Every margin or space around this environment (when this environment is used in a text) is zero.

Since I know few about macros, every attempt I tried to make an environment satisfying 1-4 has failed. Can anyone help me?

Comment: your example is not very clear, since you are suggesting using `$` around every `\alignhere` symbol (why?) do you mean that your `equation` are text not math?

Comment: Yes, I wish (some equation) to be inline math equations involving texts like 'Let $x \in A$ be an element'. (Sorry for making confusion.)

Comment: so math but in textstyle not display style? so with limits to the right of `\sum` not above  and below, `$\sum_1^n$` not `\[\sum_1^n\]` ?

Comment: Yes, it is fine to use small version of the symbols \sum, \prod, etc.

Answer (score 1):

I guess you want something like this using a `tabularx` to give a central column that allows line breaking to an unspecified width.

[image]

Note I added + as math does not allow line breaking between letters.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,tabularx}
\newenvironment{zz}
{\center\noindent\tabularx{\textwidth}{
@{}
>{\let\\\zznewline$}r<$
@{}
>{${}}c<{{}$}
@{}
>{${}}X<$
%@{}
l
@{}
}}
{\endtabularx\endcenter}
\newcommand\zznewline{\span\omit\span\omit\hfill\\}

\begin{document}

\begin{zz}
(some equation)
&\Rightarrow& (some equation) & (shortnote)\\
&\Rightarrow& (some lo+oo+oo+oo+oo+oo+oo+oo+oo+ooong + equation) & (shortnote)\\
&\Leftrightarrow& (some equation) & (shortnote)
\end{zz}


\begin{zz}
(some equation)\\
&=& (some equation) & (shortnote)\\
&=& (some lo+oo+oo+oo+oo+oo+oo+oo+oo+oo+oo+oo+oo+oo+oong + equation)& (shortnote)\\
&\subseteq& (some equation) & (shortnote)
\end{zz}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Yes, this is very close to the thing I wanted, but I thought it is cumbersome to write \text every time to write short texts when the environment is in math mode. (For example, I think 'Let $x \in A$ be an element' is better than '\text{Let } x \in A \text{ be an element}) That was the reason I wanted to use inline equations $$ in text mode instead of using \text in math mode.

Comment: @Luka sorry I honestly don't know what you mean. This sets the first three columns in math mode, and the final "note" column in text mode, I thoughtthat was what you needed.

Comment: I am really sorry for making a lot of confusion... What you have made above is close enough to what I have thought. I really appreciate for your help.

Comment: I was just typing and my computer blue screened:-) I was going to say you can delete the `$` from the tabaularx preamble then add them to the table body when you want math mode, if you prefer. @Luka

Comment: @Luka as I said above: simply remove the `$` from the definition.

Comment: There are 6 $ in the definition making the first three columns math by default, take them out and they will be text.

Comment: I got it!! This is what I exactly wanted. I really want to thank you for your help.