# Why does 'tabbing' use two different symbols '\=' and '\>' while 'align' uses only '&'?

Tags: align, tabbing

The 'tabbing' environment uses two symbols '\=' and '\>';

'\=' in the first line defines the point of alignment,
and '\>' aligns texts in other lines to the designated points.

However, the symbol '&' in 'align' environment seems to work in both ways (to define points of alignment *and* align texts).

How can this happen? What's the difference between 'tabbing' and 'align'?

Can we modify the 'tabbing' environment to use only a single symbol (thus, unite '\=' and '\>') and make it work like 'align'?

Comment: Why? They serve different purposes, so why would you want to conflate them? What's the usecase?

Comment: Actually, I am working with this problem. https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/574687/customized-alignment-of-texts-and-inline-equations I want to define a command  ('\alignhere' and '\notehere' in the link above) that can work in both '\\=' and '\\>' as the symbol '&' in 'align', so there's no need to distinguish two symbols and define two different commands.

Comment: the two environments work differently  `align` gives no possibility to specify the alignment of each cell so you just need to mark the cell boundaries, `tabbing` (for which I don't think I have ever found a use in 30 years of using latex) allows the alignments in each cell to be specified in different ways and uses a text line to set the alignment points. Why would you expect these to have similar command structure?

Comment: I didn't notice the difference in each cell... Then is there any 'text' version of 'align'? It is cumbersome to write \text every time when one wants to align texts.

Comment: why don't you use a tabular?